# How To Compare Only The Date?

Tags: c#, sql

```
 public void display()
        {
            string query = "select * from Entry where arrival_time = '" + DateTxtBox.Text + "' and checkpoint_id = '" + CheckpointTxtBox.Text + "'";
            DataTable dt = cn.retrieve(query);
            TrafficGridView.DataSource = dt;
}
```

As you can see, the code above compares the value of those two textboxes with the values present in the database and returns the rows which are affected.

Problem: arrival_time has datatype DateTime. It works when I enter 2017-04-28 3:43:08 AM in the textbox. But I just want to enter 2017-04-28. And I do not want to change the datatype. Is there any way? Please help

Comment: Yes, convert it at application code or in database and compare

Comment: What happens when a malicious user enters `'; delete from Entry; --` into one of your text boxes? You need to read up on query parametrisation.

Comment: What's your DBMS ?? SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, .... ??

Comment: Its SQL Server. Thanks for letting me know about that flaw. I am beginner and this is my college project. I will work on the security features after I complete this step. Thanks again :)